# sql check column value included 2

Tags: oracle

My column type is `Number`, and this number rule is

```
1,2 => 3 
1,2,4 => 7
2,4 => 6
```

Finally, I will save the result, ex 3, 7, 6.

It's a sum of binary. can I check include 2 on the where condition? Thanks your help.

---

#### edit

example

```
| id | type | data |
|----|------|------|
| 1  |  2   | test |
| 2  |  3   | test2|
| 3  |  1   | test3|
| 4  |  6   | test4|
```

The result is I want.

```
| id | type | data |
|----|------|------|
| 1  |  2   | test |
| 2  |  3   | test2|
| 4  |  6   | test4|
```

sql ex

```
select * from test_table where type "include 2";
```

Comment: Please post your attempts to eliminate unnecessary assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for my goal. I can use `bitand` function [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions014.htm).

```
select * from test_table where bitand(type, 2) = 2;
```